# vim: view compressed document, your location within it, in sidebar (similar to Sublime's mini-map)?

Tags: vim

This might have been answered already, but I have not been able to find this question, so gonna ask myself:

Is there a vim plugin that allows you to view a snapshot of the whole document you're editing on the side, indicating where you are in that document? Similar to Sublime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime call this a mini map and unfortunately there are no "perfect" plugin for vim that provides this functionality.

You could try [vim-minimap](https://github.com/severin-lemaignan/vim-minimap) or [minimap-vim](https://github.com/koron/minimap-vim) and see if they work for your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

The only plugin that extracts information from the source code about the document is [TagBar](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/), which, unfortunately, does not have this feature.

As far as I know there is no plugin that imitate this feature.